# Request Advice: How to Log WCF Web Service Request Info to a database

Tags: c#, wcf

I am pretty new to coding .NET web services. I find myself writing a .NET WCF application with about 20 web services. I would like to log the following events:

1. Request (With Payload - who and what)
2. Response (Did the query work, was data returned)
3. Errors (Was there some sort of error)

I wrote a simple function that does a SQL insert at each point. Every web service request gets at least two inserts - one at the request and another at the response. Each of the 10+ methods needs at least 4 of these logging calls. Too much maintenance in my book.

I think this approach too hard and cumbersome - I will need to do a great deal of work to maintain it. I have used LOG4J (I didn't configure) with Axis2 in the past, it was able to log all of the above in the web server. The exceptions needed to be thrown, but the request/response logging was handled automagically. I don't know .NET well enough to feel like I have a good handle on my options.

At this point I am considering Log4net or the Enterprise Library Semantic Logging Application Block. Do I have better choices? Any suggestions as to which course might be easiest for a relative newbie?

Thanks,
Matt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution to your problem needs to be divided in two:

1. How to easily capture the request/response for each operation contract? (that is w/o adding special code at the beginning/end of each method)?
2. How to effectively load the data into the data base?

For 1: You can create a message inspector and register it as a service behavior. This means that you will have a *single* point that intercepts all the requests and responses- allowing you to handle them in one place. [This article](http://cgeers.com/2011/05/10/wcf-message-logging/) that explains how to write and deploy such an inspector. It is very easy.

For 2: log4net and ENtLiB are definitely primary candidates.

Some considerations for choosing:

- In terms of logging capabilities, for most scenarios, they are both equally powerful.
- log4net's API is friendlier in my opinion
- EntLib is a large (but well factored) library. But it does carry much more dependencies that log4not. If you don't plan to use other modules than logging, it is probably an overkill

Regardless of your choice, you need to take into account performance considerations. You did not mention how many request you expect, but in large numbers, logging each one can impede performance. 
There are various strategies to deal with that but that's a story for after you profile your application.

Answer (score 0):

In the event that you are just looking for transaction audit logging (perhaps to support the development, debugging and early implementation phases), then you may want to consider using the WCF Tracing and Message Logging capabilities. The WCF tracing functionality provides a relatively simple, built-in method to monitor communication to/from WCF services. For test and debugging environments, configure informational or verbose activity tracing and enable message logging. The combination of activity tracing and message logging should prove beneficial when initially deploying and testing new services or adding new operations and/or communication bindings to existing services.  If you are concerned about maintenance, then you can setup the trace log to use a set size and then "re-cycle" the file space.

The following links provide a good overview:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa702726.aspx